# React-icons error 'Cannot use import statement outside a module' in stackblitz

Tags: reactjs, stackblitz

I'm trying to add icon in my social header, but I am getting this error:

> Cannot use import statement outside a module

and here is code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BsLinkedin } from 'react-icons/bs';

const HeaderSocial = () => {
  return (
    <div className="header_socials">
      <a href="https://linkedin.com" target="_blank">
        <BsLinkedin />
      </a>
      <a href="https://github.com" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeaderSocial;
```

and project source code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3nbkch?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHeader%2FheaderSocial.jsx).

Comment: try deleting `node_modules` folder and `run npm install` see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have jest.config.js and your jest configs are in package.json, you can fix this problem by adding these lines.

```
 "transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|react-native-vector-icons)/)"
]
```

So your package.json will have lines like that ...

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native|react-native-vector-icons)/)"
    ]
  }
```